# Excel 2013 VBA - For Next Loop Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, iteration

I'm almost embarrassed to post this, but I am dumbfounded. 6 months ago, I wrote a VERY simple For/Next Loop to cycle through the cells of a column and, if certain criteria was met, perform an action. It has worked flawlessly for the past 6 months. Today, it quit working.

---

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim DateCell As String
Dim LastRow As Variant

LastRow = Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next

For x = 2 To LastRow

    DateCell = Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A" & x)

    If Right(DateCell, 4) = "2015" Then
      Else
       Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A" & x).Select
       Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A" & x).Value = Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A" & x - 1).Value
   End If

Next x

On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox ("Done! " & x & " rows analyzed.")
End Sub
```

---

When I step through to the "For" line, it sets the value of x to zero. When it gets to the "Next x" line, it increments it to 1, but then doesn't loop...instead it goes to "On Error" and finishes. I even tried setting x = 2 before the loop, but same thing....it will increment to 3 and then exit the loop.

What could have changed? I even went back to my original file and tried running it, same thing.

Comment: What's the value of `LastRow` (and why are you using a `Variant` rather than `Long`?)? Also I suggest  you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line and run the code.

Comment: What value is in `LastRow` when you step through without altering the value of x?

Comment: Might sound stupid - but is there actually data in column A of the `Paste Here` sheet?

Comment: Not the cause but, If your data ever gets above 32768 rows you will have an error here  Dim x As Integer as that is the limit of an integer.  Change it  to Dim x As Long.

Comment: Why does it set x=0 when the loop states for x = 2?

Answer (score 0):

Matthew was on the right track. Because of this line:
   LastRow = Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
If you have something in a cell in column A above A65536 and below cell A32768 then VBA will just set x to 0 and the loop will not execute.